# Using foreign key relationships in Views entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to step through a model's foreign key to access another model in a View? I want to return one type of model to my view, but get the data from another model. For example, in my view:

```
@[ModelObject].[Field (ForeignKey)].[ForeignKey Field]
```

**Edit:**

Your feedback has been helpful so far, and it sounds like a View Model might be the way to go, but allow me to provide a little more information so that you can better advise.

I have an `x.Id`, and I want to find all `Y` objects that are associated with `x.Id` -- this mapping is held in a table `XYMap` where several `Y.Id`s map to one `X.Id`. Both of these models are in the same entity:

```
public class X
{
    [Key]
    public int xId {get; set;}
}

public class XYMap
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Y")]
    public int yId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("X")]
    public int xId { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    [Key]
    public int yId { get; set; }
}
```

What I have tried to do is, given an `x.Id` called `someXid`:

```
var yIdList = db.XYMap.Where(item => item.xId == someXid).ToList()
```

I want to get all of the Y objects so I can display their data in the view.

Comment: if you're using entity framework, and you've mapped the navigation, you should just be able to linq.include("entity-name"); I think this will get you what you want (eager loading rather than lazy loading)

Comment: I hadn't mapped navigation, and so it wasn't showing up. Got it now. Still wondering if this is going to result in excessive db hits as amhed said below.

Comment: this should lead to opposite. Eager load once. Transfer payloads will be bigger. But MVC is optimized to handle them.

Comment: To clarify, use navigational eager loading. Turn off Lazy loading. Minimum hit to db.

Comment: I was able to use eager loading for `Y` in this example -- but then it goes further, with another foreign key (`x->y->z`) and I can't seem to do an eager load of `Z` since it's not directly related to the `XY` model. At least I'm on the right track now, though.

Comment: I have had success going x->y->z. Either way you're on the right track.

Comment: Ah ha! The trick was just to use a dot operator in the include. `EntityContext.XY.Include("Y").Include("Y.Z").Where(item=>item.some_x == some_x")`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not recommended. Perhaps the navigational property is setup with lazy loading and calling @Model.NavigationalField from the view results in a call to the database. The view shouldn't be responsible for these kind of calls.

I would recommend creating a ViewModel that combines the properties that you need from both entities.

Comment: There's definitely a noticeable performance decline when lazy loading objects through the view.

Comment: I would avoid Lazy loading. increased payloads have their own hits.